# How can I import the Rally user stories into JIRA?

Tags: jira, rally

Any answer or approach would be really appreciated. Please help!

Comment: Hi user, StackOverflow is a site for programming questions. This question doesn't look like it has anything to do with code — can you make it more clear what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

The [Rally Connector for JIRA](https://help.rallydev.com/jira-5-installation-user-guide) is the usual way of getting user stories from Rally to JIRA. It's designed to be an integration, but it can also be used for a one time import.

Comment: Thanks Scott. What do you mean by one time import? Can this not be done again. our aim is to migrate from Rally to JIRA so we want to copy/ move the user stories from rally to JIRA using this connector. This can be done right?

Comment: I assumed you wanted a one-time transfer only because you wrote "import"--but yes, the connector was designed for continuous integrations, moving issues from one system to the other on a regular basis. The connector works OK on a one-way basis, but in my experience, the bidirectional synchronization is not appropriate for any org that cares about data integrity. The connector maintains no state and it is incapable of performing a 3-way merge, so if two people edit the same issue on both systems at roughly the same time (even different fields!), one side will silently lose data.

Comment: In the other direction, even in a one-way configuration, the connector is also susceptible to race conditions when moving newly-created JIRA issues to Rally. If a JIRA user creates an issue and then immediately edits it, and the connector runs while the user still has the "edit" page open, and then the user saves the JIRA edit, the connector will create duplicate artifacts in Rally. We tried to get Rally to fix it, but this bug apparently did not rank high on their priority list. We ended up having to patch the connector ourselves!

Comment: Anyway, if you are planning to get rid of Rally and move to JIRA permanently, then the connector should be able to do the job for you. The one thing to watch out for is that, by default, it only processes the issues/artifacts that were created since the last time it ran (since it wants to be a continuous integration). Luckily, it writes a timestamp file in the current directory to record that date. IIRC it's a single-line text file that contains the UNIX timestamp of the last run date, so it should be easy to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do a one-off import you can also retrieve the issues from Rally, format them into CSV and use the JIRA CSV Importer. We do this for customers at ServiceRocket pretty regularly, though it's not a small task

Comment: Thanks Mdoar. I tried this as well however this requires a lot of formatting and manual tasks in mapping fields and so we wanted to look into the connector thing first.